# Calculate integrals $\int_{{\pi \over 4}}^{\arctan {1 \over 2}} {{{\sqrt {{\mathop{\rm cos}\nolimits u} } } \over {\sqrt {\sin u} }}du} $

Tags: integration

This is my homework. And it's really a challenge for me. Can anyone solve this.

> $$\large\int\limits_{{\pi  \over 4}}^{\arctan {1 \over 2}} {{\sqrt{\cos u}   \over {\sqrt {\sin u} }}du} $$

Comment: did you try rewriting $\frac{\sqrt{\cos u}}{\sqrt{\sin u}}$ as $\frac1{\sqrt{\tan u}}$ and then use the substitution $x = \sqrt{\tan u}$?

Comment: i tried set t=sinu and change variable. But it seem i went to wrongway.

Comment: this intergrals ogrinal is $${1 \over {\sqrt {\tan u} }}$$

Comment: then $u = arctan x^2$ and $du = \frac{2xdx}{1+x^4}$ it seems, and under the integral you get $\frac{2xdx}{x(1+x^4)} = \frac{2dx}{1+x^4}$ if i'm right

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the integral as follows:
$$
\int \sqrt{\cot u}~ du
$$
Let's set $$I_1=\int (\sqrt{\tan u}+\sqrt{\cot u})~du$$

By taking $u=\arctan t^2$ so $du= \frac{2t}{1+t^4}dt$ and then:
 $$I_1=2\int \frac{t(t+\frac{1}{t})}{1+t^4}dt=2\int \frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{(t-\frac{1}{t})^2+2}dt$$

Now, setting $t-\frac{1}{t}=z$, we get $(1+\frac{1}{t^2})dt=dz$ and $I_1$ would be changed to:

$$I_1=2\int \frac{1}{z^2+2}dz =\sqrt{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c=\sqrt{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan u}-\sqrt{\cot u}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$$

By the similar way, if we take $$I_2=\int (\sqrt{\tan u}-\sqrt{\cot u})du$$
then, in denominator make term $(t+1/t)^2-1$ and substitute $t+1/t=z$ next. This gives us $I_2$. Now we have:

$$I_3=\int \sqrt{\cot u}du=\frac{I_1-I_2}{2}$$

I let you put the bounds and calculate the value!

Comment: How can you think this solution ? Awesome.

Comment: @TienQuan It is available in some calculus books

Comment: @Babak Thanks for well-editing.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I=&\int\sqrt{\cot u} \ du \\
\ =&\sqrt{2}\int \frac{\cos u\ du}{\sqrt{\sin 2u}}\\
\ =&I_1+I_2
\end{split}
\end{equation} where $$I_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\cos u-\sin u}{\sqrt{(\cos u+\sin u)^2-1}}du$$ and $$I_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\cos u+\sin u}{\sqrt{1-(\sin u-\cos u)^2}}du$$

Since $$\frac{d}{du}(\cos u+\sin u)=\sin u-\cos u$$ and $$\frac{d}{du}(\sin u-\cos u)=\cos u+\sin u$$ we get after replacing $\cos u+\sin u$ by $z$ and $-\cos u+\sin u$ by $t$ $$I_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})+c_1\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln(\cos u+\sin u+\sqrt{\sin 2u})+c_1$$ and $$I_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arcsin(t)+c_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arcsin(\sin u-\cos u)+c_2$$

Now, you can evaluate the integral by putting the bounds.